# using selenium IWebDriver, firefox keep timing out?

Tags: c#, selenium

since an downgrade of firefox 42, I keep having a weird behavior... When setting a IWebDriver with firefox, it does open the browser, but then it timeouts every time! Why would it timeout like this?

Here is the code I use to open it

```
string remoteAddress = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile.ToBase64String());
capabilities.SetCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

Comment: Firefox 64 bits version doesn't seem to be supported by my current version of selenium, works with a 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you're using latest Selenium package - it should do the work.